# Indesign: links went blurry. Not a Display Performance issue

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, resolution

Everything was fine in my indesign project and i sent it home from my desktop at work so i can work on it at home from my laptop. All my Jpgs went blurry! these are huge images that i downloaded from Unsplash. Sent it back to my Desktop and still the same issue. It's in High Quality Display and still looks pixelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make certain the image links are still valid. Especially if you are moving the INDD file back and forth between workstations. Broken image links will use low resolution previews.

Comment: Thank you !!! That was it . Have to remember to package everything properly before transferring

Answer (score 1):

Basicly what Scott is saying. Bring up the Links panel via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and if you see any question mark icons up there, that means missing or broken links, which will result in your images defaulting to a low res preview.

When you move projects around, make sure the entire 'Links' and 'Document fonts' folders are included for a working package.

[image]